# jsonapi-resources; wrong self link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I configured json-resouce-api.
But the self link generated by json-resource-api is wrong.

The code seems to checks the module hierarchy of the resource class and completely ignores how rails generates the routes.

### routes.rb

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      # resources :subscriptions, only: [:index, :new, :create]
      # jsonapi_resources :subscriptions, only: [:index, :new, :create]
      jsonapi_resources :subscriptions
    end
  end
```

### resouces/api/V1/subscription_recource.rb

```
class Api::V1::SubscriptionResource < JSONAPI::Resource
   attributes :id, :third-service_id, :created_at, :updated_at
   model_name 'Subscription'

   # def custom_links(options)
   #  {self: nil}
   # end
end
```

What I got => `http://api.localhost.local:3000/api/v1/subscriptions/1`
but it should be `http://api.localhost.local:3000/subscriptions/1`

How can I fix this?

### UPDATE

`rake routes`

```
[DUPLICATE ATTRIBUTE] `id` has already been defined in SubscriptionResource.
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
api_v1_subscriptions GET    /subscriptions(.:format)     api/v1/subscriptions#index {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                     POST   /subscriptions(.:format)     api/v1/subscriptions#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
 api_v1_subscription GET    /subscriptions/:id(.:format) api/v1/subscriptions#show {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                     PATCH  /subscriptions/:id(.:format) api/v1/subscriptions#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                     PUT    /subscriptions/:id(.:format) api/v1/subscriptions#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                     DELETE /subscriptions/:id(.:format) api/v1/subscriptions#destroy {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
        stripe_event        /stripe-events               StripeEvent::Engine
```

### UPDATE2

This issue is totally the same as github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/issues/591
Monkey Pack can be applied, but it's little bit risky.
For now ( 2016, Oct 5th ), I couldn't find any other ways than

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      jsonapi_resources :subscriptions
    end
  end
```

Comment: Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: "" do
  namespace :v1, path: "" do
    jsonapi_resources :subscriptions
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I'd love to remove `v1` from the uri. so that  it should return `http://api.localhost.local:3000/subscriptions/1`

Comment: Thanks again. but I still got    "self": "http://api.localhost.local:3000/api/v1/subscriptions/1"

Comment: @Toshi Can you run `rake routes | grep api` and show me your content ?

Comment: I think this issue is totally the same as https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/issues/591

Answer (score 0):

Adding `jsonapi_relationships` worked for me:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: "" do
  namespace :v1, path: "" do
    jsonapi_resources :subscriptions do
      jsonapi_relationships
    end
  end
en
```